# Is there any way to move my answer from one question to another?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

A few days after answering a question on *Mathematics*, I noticed that it had been marked as duplicate.

I know that questions marked as duplicate are sometimes deleted after a while, though I'm not quite sure when.

In any case, I feel that my answer is contributing, and I would hate to see it deleted along with the question.

I can post it on the original question, but it will not be ideal for several reasons:

1. It will "lose" the activity around it (votes, comments, etc)
2. It will essentially appear as if I am answering a two-month old question
3. It will be duplicated over two questions until the one marked duplicate is deleted

Is there any way to "migrate" my answer from the duplicate question to the original question?

The two questions can be found here:

- [Original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1153333/131263)
- [Duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1214137/131263)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't.

The options at hand:

- Delete your answer and repost. Yes, you lose your rep.
- Get the questions merged. Not likely if the question isn't that good. Merging takes some moderator effort, so you need to flag one of the questions with a custom flag reason.
- Get the 'closed as duplicate' reversed: this propably just needs community intervention (people able to vote to close). This will only happen if the old question/answer set is much worse than the new one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saying merging is "not likely if the question isn't that good." Do you mean the potential merge target? If it's not good, it shouldn't have been used as a duplicate target.

Answer (score 8):

To answer your three concerns in order:

### It will "lose" the activity around it (votes, comments, etc)

Take any comments into account in updating your new answer if necessary. Comments are meant to be transient anyway. And, if the answer is good, it'll get votes in the new place.

### It will essentially appear as if I am answering a two-month old question

This is fine, as long as your answer doesn't just duplicate what's already there. If it does, no need to add yours as well. But if yours is an improvement (for whatever metric for that you want), *answering old questions is fine*, since one of the goals of Stack Exchange is to build up a canonical repository of answers. There's even a [badge for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer).

## It will be duplicated over two questions until the one marked duplicate is deleted

That's easy. Once you've posted it in the new place, delete the original *answer* yourself. This goes back to your first concern (loss of any reputation gained), but if the answer got at least +3, there's a consolation prize — the ["Disciplined" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/disciplined). And again, if the answer is good, you'll probably earn it back anyway.

(At least, unless it's accepted. In that case, not much to do, although I guess you could replace it with a link to the new answer.)

---

I agree it would be handy to have this (especially because it would encourage collection of all answers in one place where they can be voted up or down next to each other), but it doesn't seem strongly necessary since the drawbacks are small. (And relative to other site functions, it's not that common, so is probably not worth the design, development, and maintenance.)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer and detailed reference to each section.